# Carrying a laptop battery with a cracked case onto a flight

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security, electronic-items, batteries

I'm flying to Spain from the UK with Avios. I have a laptop with an "extended" battery (so the battery pokes out of the back of the laptop); the case on this battery has cracked, and the *cell itself* is exposed; you can see the terminal connection, too.

I want to know if I'm likely to be let on the flight with it as it is, or if I should put tape (duct or otherwise) over it, or if I shouldn't bring my laptop at all. It would be a great disadvantage if I can't bring my laptop with me.

I found a page [here](https://www.caa.co.uk/Passengers/Before-you-fly/Baggage/Items-that-are-allowed-in-baggage/) that describes *extra* batteries which are separate from the equipment:

> Any battery that has been removed must be protected against short circuit (by placing it in its original retail packaging or by otherwise insulating terminals, e.g. by taping over exposed terminals or placing each battery in a separate bag or protective pouch).

However I'm not sure if the same applies for a Li-Ion battery that's *in* my computer to begin with. I'm worried that taping the exposed end would look suspicious, too. Should I also take the battery out of the laptop at security? The laptop is in perfectly usable condition and the only problem is that the battery is exposed (and may be tampered with) in its current state.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that just a health/fire/safety hazard already? And is there a good reason you won't just buy a new battery?

Comment: Please don't carry that battery on to a flight, or indeed, keep it at all. Dispose of it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 11):

Avios isn't an airline. Presumably you are flying with British Airways or Iberia, which are owned by the same parent company. From BA's [list of banned and restricted items](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials/liquids-and-restrictions#):

> Please always ensure that you:
>
> [...]
>
> - Don't take any damaged batteries or equipment with you.

By using a damaged lithium ion battery you are endangering yourself, and by taking it on an aircraft, you are endangering your fellow passengers. Even visually undamaged lithium ion batteries can fail catastrophically without warning. The battery casing is intended to protect the cells from damage. Without this protection, they are at a much higher risk of damage, and subsequently, fire.

You should stop using the battery, and dispose of it as soon as possible, according to the laws for electronic waste recycling where you currently are. You should absolutely not travel with this battery on an aircraft.